# No storage on my samsung s3 mini

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, storage

Why is my samsung s3 mini saying that I have no storage when I clearly have aload of space from deleting data; pictures, apps and music files?

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts, harriet! From what you specified, I can only guess – it would help if you [edit] your question and provide some more details. Where does it say "no storage" – and what *exactly* does it say? A screenshot would be helpful, too – also a summary of what *Settings → Storage* shows. I'm *guessing* it says "insufficient storage", and further guess you've deleted stuff from your SDCard only. Could that be? If not, where did you delete "data" from?

Comment: More info needed to give you an answer!

Comment: For user @conpertura : Is there free space on BOTH the internal memory and SD card?Have you tried deinstalling apps?Are you confident with replacing your phone's operating system? If you are, I recommend the third option since Cyanogenmod 11 uses a lot less memory than the preinstalled Android system and also lets you use the whole memory capacity. There is a stable version for your phone available in this xda thread. Just keep exactly to the installation guide!

Answer (score 0):

You have to ensure that you have space in the internal memory of your phone, and not just on SD card. You can see it on Settings->Storage. If you have internal space, I recommend you install and run Ccleaner app. Otherwise, a radical solution will be a reset in your device. Don't forget to create a backup first!